# IOS Application not submitting POST request with images (.png, .jpeg) on React Native (Expo)

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I have a screen that is responsible for sending a POST request to the backend to upload static files to S3 (it supports .pdf and images).

The function works normally when running locally with expo (both in Android and IOS), but it doesn't work with images on IOS when I create the build (the app is running on TestFlight already). In Android it works perfectly fine.

I thought that it was throwing an error on the backend, but when I debugged with the logfiles, I noticed the requests never reached the server. And the error ONLY occurs with images (both with the camera and from the Files). If I upload a PDF, the request is successful and the file is uploaded to S3

here is the function that sends the image:

```
const sendEssay = async () => {
    if (onLoadToken) await onLoadToken(); // update token

    await FileSystem.uploadAsync(`${API_URL}/essays/upload_essay_view/`, selectedImageGallery ?? selectedImageCamera, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `JWT ${authState.accessToken}`,
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        uploadType: FileSystem.FileSystemUploadType.MULTIPART,
        httpMethod: 'POST',
        fieldname: 'essay',
        parameters: {
            essay_id: essay_id.toString(),
            comment: comment ?? '',
        },
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        alert("Essay sent successfully!");
        navigation.goBack();
    }).catch((error) => {
        alert('Error sending the essay:' + error);

        console.log(error.message);
        setIsSending(false);
        setFileName(null);
        setFileType(null);
        setSelectedImageCamera(null);
        setSelectedImageGallery(null);
    });
}
```

the function that gets the picture from the camera:

```
const openCamera = async () => {
    const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== 'granted') {
        alert('Sorry, we need camera permissions to take photos!');
        return;
    }

    let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
        allowsEditing: false, // Setting to 'false' to disable cropping
        aspect: [4, 3],
        quality: 1,
    });

    if (result.canceled) {
        console.log('User canceled image selection');
    } else if (result.assets && result.assets.length > 0) {
        const selectedFormat = result.assets[0].uri.split('.').pop()?.toLowerCase();
        console.log('Image taken:', result.assets[0].uri, 'Format:', selectedFormat);

        if (selectedImageGallery) {
            setSelectedImageGallery(null);
        }

        setFileName(result.assets[0].fileName);
        setFileType(result.assets[0].type);
        setSelectedImageCamera(result.assets[0].uri);
    }
};
```

the function that gets the picture from the galery:

```
const openGallery = async () => {
    try {
        const result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({

            type: ['image/*', 'application/pdf'],
        });
        console.log(result);

        if (!result.canceled) {
            console.log('File selected:', result.assets[0].uri ?? '', 'File Name:', fileName);

            const fileExtension = "." + result.assets[0].uri.split('.').pop()?.toLowerCase();
            console.log('File extension:', fileExtension);

            if (selectedImageCamera) {
                setSelectedImageCamera(null);
            }

            if (fileExtension && ['.png', '.jpeg', '.jpg', '.pdf'].includes(fileExtension)) {
                setFileName(result.assets[0].name);
                setSelectedImageGallery(result.assets[0].uri ?? '');
                setFileType(result.assets[0].mimeType);
            } else {
                alert('Invalid file format. Only .png, .jpeg, .jpg, and .pdf are allowed.');
            }
        } else {
            console.log('User canceled selection');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error selecting file:', error);
    }
};
```

I tried multiple times to upload the .png files, taking pictures from the camera and using images from the Files, but it never reached the server. I am suspecting it is missing some image upload pemission on IOS